# Does every operator on complex vector space have a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Result: Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional **complex** vector space and $T:V \to V$ is a linear map. Then $T$ has  an [upper triangular matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperTriangularMatrix.html) with respect to some basis of $V.$ [For the proof see: Linear algebra done right by sheldon axler third edition, p.149]

--

**My claim is**: Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional **complex** vector space and $T:V \to V$ is a linear map. Then $T$ has  a [diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix) with respect to some basis of $V.$

**Here is my proof**: Assume dim $V=n.$  Since $V$ is complex vector space, $T$ has an eigenvalue, say $\lambda_1$ (This is known fact). There for there is nonzero vector $v_1\in V$
such that $$Tv_1= \lambda_1 v_1$$.

Put $U_1=\text{span} (v_1).$ Note that $U_1$ is a subspace of $V.$ Then there is subspace $W\subset V$ such that 
$$V= U_1\oplus W$$
and dim $W=n-1.$

Again, we may say that $T$ is linear map on a complex vector space $W,$ and therefore it has a eigenvalue, say $\lambda_2$, and the corresponding eigenvector $0\neq v_2\in W$ and $Tv_2= \lambda_2 v_2.$

We may continue this process, and I think, we get $v_1, v_2,..., v_n$ linearly independent eigenvector of $T$. And therefore the matrix of $T$ with respec to this basis is diagonal.

> **My Question**: Is my claim is correct? If not, where is  the mistake in proof?

Comment: No, also in the complex case it may happen that some eigenvalue is not regular. Take the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $a_{12}=1$ and all the other entries are $0$. Its only eigenvalue is $0$, so if $A$ were diagonalizable, it would be similar to the zero matrix, absurd.

Comment: How do you know you get $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors? Have you considered the case where we have repeated eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is not correct. An error in your proof is that $T$ is not a linear map on $W$. Of course you can restrict $T$ to $W$, but for $w \in W$, there is no reason for $T(w)$ to be in $W$, so you have a map from $W$ to $V$.

For a counterxample, consider the map on $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by 
$(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (z_2,0)$.

For more information on what is true, look up Jordan Canonical Form.